# Why the mass assignment code does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, mass-assignment

There is a mass assignment defined in sys_log model in our rails 3.1.4 app:

```
attr_accessible :log_date, :user_name, :user_id, :user_ip, :action_logged, :as => :new_log
```

A method is defined in application_controller to save the log:

```
  def sys_logger(action_logged)
    log = SysLog.new(:log_date => Time.now, :user_id => session[:user_id], :user_name => session[:user_name], :user_ip => session[:user_ip],
                     :action_logged => action_logged, :as => :new_log)
    log.save
  end
```

However, the mass assignment does not work. Here is the warning message:

```
WARNING: Can't mass-assign protected attributes: log_date, user_id, user_name, 
user_ip, action_logged, as
```

:new_log is not working as defined. What's wrong with the code above?  Thanks so much.

Comment: I am going to guess looking up that warning message would yield useful results ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `:as => :new_log` is now part of the hash of attributes, instead of a separate option you pass in.

Adding some curly braces should help:

```
def sys_logger(action_logged)
  log = SysLog.new({:log_date => Time.now, :user_id => session[:user_id],
                    :user_name => session[:user_name], :user_ip => session[:user_ip], 
                    :action_logged => action_logged }, :as => :new_log)
  log.save
end
```

Or assigning it temporarily:

```
def sys_logger(action_logged)
  attrs = { :log_date => Time.now, :user_id => session[:user_id],
            :user_name => session[:user_name], :user_ip => session[:user_ip],
            :action_logged => action_logged }
  log = SysLog.new(attrs, :as => :new_log)
  log.save
end
```

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks. What we have missed is ruby hash should be with braces. Or as a var like the params[:model_name] used in controllers mass assignment. Thanks again.